# What is the difference between different provinces in India food culture?

Tags: india, food-and-drink

So I know some things about regional variations in food culture. Kerala is the Indian seafood masters. Hyderabad has the best goat curries probably in the world. Goat being a meat that does not offend the Muslim or the Hindus. Hyderabad during Ramadan being a special experience.

So I'm going to be honest I want to go to India for the food. ( don't judge me. ). So what hints could people who know India well tell me of specific regional cuisine, so when this covid malarkey eventually ends I can know which part of India to go to?

Comment: There was a TV searies starring chef Gordon Ramsay. Maybe you can catch the India episodes to get an idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon%27s_Great_Escape

Comment: This question is very broad, even within one single area there are many variations and nothing is regulated, so it will take several lifetimes to explore all, or even one area. Not sure it can be answered within the Stack Exchange rules.